Nginx Proxy, Cloudflare Full SSL, and Load Balancer Redirection Loop?
I'm facing an issue with a redirection loop when using Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of my load balancer. My setup is as follows:
Domain: aarohisilks.com
DNS: Cloudflare, A record pointing to my proxy server's IP, SSL mode set to "Full-strict"
Proxy Server (Nginx): Terminates SSL, forwards traffic to the load balancer on port 80
Load Balancer (Nginx): Distributes traffic to backend servers
Proxy Configuration inside my proxy server
/etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf
# Temporary configuration for ACME challenge
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^.*$;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/html;
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}

 #Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for all domains
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^.*$;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


# SSL configuration for proxy subdomain
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name gateway.enlivendesigners.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gateway.enlivendesigners.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gateway.enlivendesigners.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://load_backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
# SSL configuration for staging subdomains
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name staging.aarohisilks.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.aarohisilks.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.aarohisilks.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://staging_backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
# SSL configuration for production subdomains
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name aarohisilks.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/aarohisilks.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/aarohisilks.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://load_backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Proxy Upstream Configuration /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf)
upstream load_backend {
    #server 194.163.168.18;  # Prod1 server
    server 148.135.73.76; #loadbalncer
}

upstream staging_backend {
    server 81.0.218.72;  # Staging server
}

Load Balancer Configuration (/etc/nginx/sites-available/load_balancer.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name aarohisilks.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://production_backend;
        # ... (proxy headers)
    }
}

Load Balancer Upstream Configuration (/etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf)
upstream production_backend {
    server 194.163.168.18; 
    server 194.163.166.206; 
}


When I try to access https://aarohisilks.com, I get the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS." I suspect this is due to a redirection loop caused by the following:
The proxy redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.
This causes a continuous loop of redirects between Cloudflare and the proxy.
I've verified that the backend servers (194.163.168.18 and 194.163.166.206) are working correctly.
Also I have sent the request to  only to the proxy without any load balancer I declare my server ip in upstream conf.
In my live server which is ip 194.163.168.18, 194.163.166.206 I have installed cyberpanel and using cyberpanel I am hosting wordpress websites. Without the load balancer site works well.
Are there any potential configuration changes I should make to either my proxy server, load balancer, or Cloudflare settings?
All the ports are opn 443,80,22

Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.
